# JQuery multiple poll one vote

Tags: jquery, validation, cookies

I have a website, that has multiple fields(companies, products), that allow a vote up or a vote down, per that vote I want only one vote for field, per user. However, I dont want anyone to register for this right. From my research if it's a single poll, a cookie seems to be the best option, (See if they polled, if so add a cookie, and don't let them vote, however, if there's say 1000 polls, how would I see if they'd voted on any single poll and not let them vote again on that poll, but other polls?) Coockies will work mostly to identify a single user, but how do I identify what they've polled on and what they have not? The individual things are defined by a company ID that is unique.
Any suggestions will be nice. The most important thing on this site is anonymity so, I cant ask them to register. I also know that they could change IP's, or delete cookies or blah, blah. But Im looking for a solution to the non, tech-savy user.

Comment: Require the user to login to vote. Record the ID of the vote they cast in a table. When you generate the HTML on the page, use a conditional statement to check if the user has voted for the id of the vote that you're casting against.

What language is your sever written in?

Comment: I don't want login, that way they can be anonymous. If it's a cookie, I can store the user, but how to store what they've voted on is the problem!

Comment: Then that system is easily exploitable and not a very safe system. You can use cookies, local storage, and session storage, you can also use sessions in PHP to determine users by their location, ip address and their user agent string. This is still non-reliable, prone to exploit, and also may even inhibit some users from being able to participate at all. perhaps you should rethink this model.

Comment: Anyway, to answer your question, you should do 3 things, check if the user has cookies enabled, then save the cookie. I would also check for local and session storages for failbacks. you can store the vote, and any other relevent information about the user in a JSON String. Save the string into the cookie/storage, and retrieve and parse at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate cookie identifier and store what polls were voted for this ID on the server. Another approach would be concatenating voted poll IDs and storing them in the cookie.

EDIT: Added [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r9ncN/) with sample implementation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var cookiename = "mypolls";

    $('input[type=button]').click(function() {

        var pollId = $(this).parent().attr('id');

        if ($.cookie(cookiename)) {

            var voted = $.cookie(cookiename);

            if (voted.indexOf('|' + pollId + '|') > -1) {

                alert('Already voted!');
                return;
            }
            else {

                voted += pollId + '|';

                // storing updated cookie
                $.cookie(cookiename, voted);
            }
        }
        else {

            // adding cookie
            $.cookie(cookiename, '|' + pollId  + '|');
        }

        alert('Thank you for your vote!');
    });
});​
```

Comment: storing a variable in the cookie? I though varoibales only stored like the url and like and id?

Comment: I can store who they are in the cookie right(im new cookies) but what about all the elements they've voted on? Only one or more?

Comment: You don't need to store who they are (you don't even know it!). Just store what polls they voted, you can concatenate all voted poll IDs into one cookie.. See that jsfiddle I added.